# Accessing virtual attribute from params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
ruby 2.1.5
rails 4.2.1
```

I am trying to figure out how to access a virtual attribute from params.

In my books_controller.rb, I have:

```
wrap_parameters :books_list

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:author_name, :book_name, :books_list)
end
```

Obviously, the books_list is the virtual attribute. I will be saving it to the books_list table

In my new.html.erb,I have:

```
<% @title = "Books" %>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <%= form_for(@books, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
          <%= f.error_notification %>

          <div class="form-inputs">
            <%= f.form_group :author_name do |f| %>
                <%= f.label :author_name, class: 'control-label col-md-2' %>
                <div class='col-md-8'>
                  <%= f.text_field :author_name, class: 'form-control' %>
                  <%= f.error_messages %>
                </div>
            <% end %>

            <div class="form-inputs">
              <%= f.form_group :book_name do |f| %>
                  <%= f.label :book_name, class: 'control-label col-md-2' %>
                  <div class='col-md-8'>
                    <%= f.text_field :book_name, class: 'form-control' %>
                    <%= f.error_messages %>
                  </div>
              <% end %>

              <%= f.form_group :books_list do |f| %>
                  <%= f.label :books_list, class: 'control-label col-md-2' %>
                  <div class='col-md-8'>
                    <%= f.text_area :books_list, class: 'form-control' %>
                    <%= f.error_messages %>
                  </div>
              <% end %>

          </div>

          <div class="form-actions col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
            <%= link_to "Cancel", test_sets_path, class: 'btn' %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I submit the form, here's what I get for params:

```
Parameters: {
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"5mxkibQHkwRnzVU31A6pe9uezsmaWeYbCUgU+gUZPLmiAZPnN6si+smdEePU0lfGITh7gmmyChf/bOY+YQQcQg==", 
  "books"=>{"author_name"=>"Some Author", "book_name"=>"Dwan Of The Dead"}, 
  "books_list"=>{"{:class=>\"form-control\"}"=>"book1\r\nbook2"}, 
  "commit"=>"Create Book List"
}
```

I am having trouble accessing the   books_list in params. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

If `books_list` column is not exist in `@book`, it raises error. 
There is no method `f.form_group` in rails, I think you use gem that defines `form_group` method.

Maybe `"books_list"=>{"{:class=>\"form-control\"}"=>"book1\r\nbook2"}` parameter is made by some bootstrap gem. you check check name attribute in html source.

Comment: No, it's not going to raise an error because it's a virtual attribute. In Rails 3, I would have had to declare it in the model as attr_accessible, but since this is Rails4, I have it in the controller product_params method.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper `product_params` method just filter parameter. Does it raise error after remove `f.form_group` block?, I think form_group method does not work well.